# hector packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

now about hector repo's i can't figure this thing ?
let say i want to deploy the slam or navigation stack on let say asctec pelican is that possible or hector is just an offline simulator only

any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42674/hector-packages/) by [ahmad malkawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1743/ahmad-malkawi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [hector_quadrotor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor) stack offers you a simulated quadrotor that can be controlled through geometry_msgs/Twist commands. I'm not sure if the asctec pelican offers a similar interface (it sure would be good if you want to use the navigation stack). If you need to use other control commands you could either write a node on top of the currently available controller or have a look at the gazebo plugins and write your own controller plugin.

In the end, SLAM (see [hector quadrotor indoor SLAM demo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor/Tutorials/Quadrotor%20indoor%20SLAM%20demo)) and the use of the navigation stack are possible on the simulated quadrotor, it's just a matter of interfacing/glue code. The problems (no odometry available, 6DOF motion etc.) are largely the same, regardless if it's a simulated or real quadrotor.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0